# cakephp3 オブジェクト型へのデータ追加について

Tags: php, cakephp

findにて繰り返しデータを取得し、データを追加していくにはどのようにすべきでしょうか。
ちょっと文字では伝えにくく、下記に例を添付します。
（jqueryのajaxにより、JSONを返すような内容です。）

1回目格納時に$aaaはobject型で[{...},{...}]となりますが、
下記のようにarray_pushすると、[{...},{...}][{...},{...},{...}]となります。
[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]のように追加するにはどのようにしたら良いでしょうか？
※一度に取得するのでなく、分けて取得している理由は、データが膨大で、メモリが高くなり、
エラーとなる為です。（例は全5件ですが、実際は何万と取得することがあります）

```
//1回目
$query = $this->Lists->find();
$lists = $query->limit(2)->offset(0);

$response = $this->response;  
$response->getBody()->write(json_encode($list1s));

//変数に格納
$aaa = $response;

//2回目
$list1s = $query->limit(3)->offset(2);
$response = $this->response;
$response->getBody()->write(json_encode($list1s));

//データを変数に追加
array_push($aaa, $response);

return $aaa;
```

Comment: そもそも当該の `$aaa` も `$response` もどちらも同じ `$this->response` を指していますよ、そもそも配列ではなくResponse。`$res->getBody()->write` で同じレスポンスに2回JSONの文字列を書き込んでいるからそのような結果になっているのでは？（試しにarray_pushを消しても動作は変わらないでしょう。）

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通り、array_pushを消しても変わりませんでした。。。
では、どのようにしたら[{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]のように返せるでしょうか。
Responseのところがよくわからず、ご教授下さい。

Answer (score 1):

lists → jsonエンコード　→　responseへjsonを書き込み　とやっているわけですから
lists ← jsonデコード　←　responseからjsonを読み出し　としないと、筋が通りません。

何かの理由で処理を調整できないなら、上記のように必要なものを取り出してください。
1関数内の話なら、lists同士を直接繋げるのが一番手っ取り早いです。

ちなみにサンプルコードは不自然にlistsやlist1sになってたりするので、
そこら辺の凡ミスもないか確認しましょう。

また細かい話ですが、listsで名前が妥当かも検討しましょう。
これだとlistのコレクション、というニュアンス、つまりコレクションのコレクション、
となります。